why there is a relation between the signal wavelength, antenna size and efficient antenna radiation?
For efficient radiation from the antenna, the size of the antenna should be one tenth or higher from the signal wavelength, why? what happens if this condition is satisfied? what happens if not?

Where does this come from? A textbook?

I’m voting to close this question because this isn't about signal processing, but about basics of antennas. Different field of engineering!

@MarcusMüller You could always cast an antenna (even if it's not an array) as a spacial sampling problem if you really wanted to! But I do think this would be better on the EE site.
